# .webp images are not showing in rich notification (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have peculiar problem where .png or .jpg images does show in ios push notification but image without extension (.webp) image is not showing

e.g.

`(https://img.host.com/isa/163853/c1/-/-/A291719_001?x=1024&y=512&ex=1024&ey=512&align=center&format=png)`

is not showing but any image with proper extension of .jpg or png does show.

I have service extension added in app but don't have content extension. also i'm using `cleverPush` sdk so basically SDK is handling rich notifications.

any help or article would be helpful.

thanks :)